# Austrailian tax resident earning salary in the UK - how much tax do I pay on foreign income?

Tags: taxes, united-kingdom, australia

I'm British citizen now living in Austraila (NSW) and am classed as a Australian tax resident.  I have a full time (remote) job for a UK company who pay my salary into my UK bank account.  I pay no UK tax on my salary as I have a UK tax code of 'NT'.  The salary is paid monthly into my UK bank account at which point I transfer some of it to my Austrailian bank account.

So my question is how much tax do I pay on this when I come to do my self-assessment in Australia?  Does foreign income count towards my tax-free allowances?

I earn around £70,000 GBP but I will not transfer all of it into my Australian bank account as transferring it cost money (even if I do use TransferWise!).  I'm also confused as to how I calculate how much AUD to put on to my tax return.  Do I have to use the rate on the day I was paid or the rate when I transferred to mu Austrailian bank account?

Any advice would be much appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: The advice is easy: hire an accountant.

Comment: @DaleM indeed I will but I like to know what needs to be done first

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This page](https://www.ato.gov.au/Individuals/Tax-Return/2013/Supplementary-tax-return/Income-questions-13-24/20---Foreign-source-income-and-foreign-assets-or-property/) and [this page](https://www.ato.gov.au/Individuals/International-tax-for-individuals/In-detail/Foreign-income-of-Australian-residents/Foreign-income-of-Australian-residents---what-you-need-to-know/) on the ATO website provide some information on tax rates.

They're rather lengthy and there's a few exceptions, but essentially, your entire foreign income, even if held overseas, is taxable. Australians are taxed worldwide.